# Django : view calls an other template (Pagination )

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```
class DamageListCriteria(TemplateView):
template_name = "damage/damagelist_criteria.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = DamageListCriteriaForm()
    general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
    args = {
        'form': form,
        'general': general
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self, request):
    general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = DamageListCriteriaForm(request.POST)
    form.non_field_errors()

    if form.is_valid():
        fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
        fdate = datetime.strptime(fromdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
        fdate = datetime.combine(fdate, datetime.min.time(), tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        print('fdate ', fdate)
        todate = form.cleaned_data['todate']
        #tdate = datetime.strptime(todate, '%d/%m/%Y') + timedelta(days=1)
        tdate = datetime.strptime(todate, '%d/%m/%Y')
        tdate = datetime.combine(tdate, datetime.max.time(), tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        print('tdate ', tdate)

        d_list = Damage.objects.filter(entry_date__range=(fdate, tdate))
        paginator = Paginator(d_list, 1)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            damage_list = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            damage_list = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            damage_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        template = "damage/damagelist_table.html"
        form = DamageListForm()
        general = General.objects.get(pk=1)

        fromdatetext = fdate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        todatetext = tdate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        args = {
            'form': form,
            'damage_list': damage_list,
            'general': general,
            'fromdate': fromdatetext,
            'todate': todatetext
        }
        return render(request, template, args)


    else:
        print('form is not valid')
        print(form.errors)
        # form = DamageEntryForm()
        args = {'form': form,
                'general': general
                }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

I want to get some criteria to make a filtering listing of my database.
It worked this way , until the moment i tried to add pagination.
The url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/damage/damage/list/criteria/

```
url(r'damage/list/criteria/$', views.DamageListCriteria.as_view(), name="damage-list-criteria"),
```

Next and Previous don't work because I am still at this url after the

```
return render(request, template, args)
```

Can i redirect somehow?
I understand that this might be the wrong way to do the listing. Can you help me , how to do it?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing to do would be not use Django itself but use Django REST framework and reuse its serializer classes along with APIView (or one of its subclasses). Are you in a position to use it or are you constrained?

Comment: I am new to Django. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Look at the pagination examples at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/ Good thing about this is it will allow you to use pagination with some classes that come with DRF itself. I recommend the PageNumberPagination class http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination , it is the simplest of the lot. If anything, DRF is the best way to implement even the filtration that you have implemented above. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/